# row and column utilisation give the same results in NumPy with Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have already a NumPy Array and it is (4,3)

When I type:

```
for column in NumPyArray:
     print(column)
```

it gives the same results as:

```
for row in NumPyArray:
     print(row)
```

In both cases the rows are operated.

Can someone tell me why is this happening and how can I operate on columns?

Comment: `for <something> in NumPyArray` iterates over the iterable and prints the elements. It doesn't matter what variable name you put in `<something>`, be it `column` or `row`. Also what's `(4,3)`?

Comment: I think [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: `for column in NumpyArray.T` should solve your problem. You need to do transpose and iterate over it.

Comment: @vb_rises I did manual transposing 3 times but your solution saved me a lot of time and effort. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, `for <anything> in NumPyArray` would always iterate on rows of a 2D array, because Python is a row-major language (the data in memory is stored in a row-major fashion).

Having a 2D array, if you want to iterate on the second dimension, you need to access the memory the other way: `a.shape == (4,3)` => `a.T.shape == (3,4)`